# how to use files from a docker volume in a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops, converters

I want to know if i can use a docker volume by many docker containers .
If so is the docker volume locked ?

Comment: For a short-lived process that's mostly oriented around reading and writing local files, it will probably be simpler to run it outside of Docker (which as a design goal makes accessing local files hard).

Comment: @DavidMaze the problem is that we're using azure functions now , any idea on how to not use docker containers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a named volume, and then use it in wherever you want, one or many dockers.

When you create a named volume, for example called `myvolume`, if you don't specify driver option, `local` is used. So, docker creates a folder in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`. Your data will persist in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvolume/_data`

Nevertheless, that was just information, you don't need to manage that. You just have to create with:

```
docker volume create myvolume
```

And then, use volume name as source.

```
docker run -v myvolume:/yourdestinationpath ...
```

If you use docker compose, syntax is the same:

```
services:
  myservice:
    ...
    volumes: 
      - myvolume:/yourdestinationpath
```

The key is that you're not using a **bind volume**, where you specify as source a concrete path to be mounted, but a docker volume name.

Answer (score 1):

This is a minimal example, in which I am mounting the local directory inside the container. My local directory will act as a persistence volume on which I can read and write from the container.

My current directory contains an `input-file` (this file shall be read by the container)
The container `cat`<sub>s</sub> the content of the `input-file` and appends it to the `output-file` (Here I am faking your *conversion*)

```
// The initial wiorking directory content
.
└── input-file

// Read the `input-file` and append its content to the `output-file` (both files are persisted on the host machine)
docker run -v $(pwd):/root/some-path ubuntu /bin/bash -c "cat /root/some-path/input-file >> /root/some-path/output-file"

// The outcome
.
├── input-file
└── output-file
```